# VBA: hold the data in copied file and delete the data in initial file

Tags: excel, vba

I would like do hold the data in copied file and delete the data in initial file. My code is :

`Sub logFormState() Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C5") = "" Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C6") = ""`  ....

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
Else
    Call logFormState
End If
End Sub
```

I'm wondering if tehere is another function to do that. The functionality of ActiveWorkbook.Saved and ActiveWorkbook.Save is not clear for me.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please provide more details about the situation. Is the "copied" file to be created during the macro or found among the open workbooks or located in a directory? What is the copied range and is it static or dynamic? Please include as many details as you can.

Comment: @Toddleson I have the file My_Doc1.xlsm where I extract some data via adodb sql queries. After I save this file as My_Doc_2_extraction.xlsm. After I close the file, when I reopen My_Doc1.xlsm again I would like to have all cells empty.

Comment: Use `Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Cells.ClearContents` to completely empty the cells.

Comment: @Toddleson Thank you, I prefore Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("C4") = "" because I have a tiltles

Comment: @Toddleson the problem is how to hold the data in cpoied file and clean the data in initial file

Comment: @Toddleson I don't know if my code is right : Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
Else
    Call logFormState
End If
End Sub